# How do I proof the theorem

Tags: inequality

Theorem:

Let $f(x,y,z)$ be a cyclic polynomial of degree $3$.

The inequality $f(x,y,z) \ge 0$ holds for all non negative variables $x,y,z$ if and only if:

$f(x,x,x)\ge0$,

$f(x,y,0) \ge 0\ ,\ \forall  (x,y)\ge 0 $

How do I start the proof of the theorem?

Comment: The homogeneous version is Stolarsky's cyclic $3$ variable inequality. However I can't find any useful links to Stolarsky's Inequality by googling (*strange*).

Comment: Search for "CD3-improved" by Pham Kim Hung, sample available at http://gil.ro/downloadable/download/sample/sample_id/1/

Comment: @Macavity You might want to put this reference as an answer.

Comment: @Wojowu Lets see if someone gets original or has a better reference...

Answer (score 3):

Search for the "CD3-improved" theorem by Pham Kim Hung, there is an excerpt / [sample available](http://gil.ro/downloadable/download/sample/sample_id/1).

The corresponding theorem for third degree symmetric polynomials is attributed to Hoo Joo Lee, the cyclic case is of course a generalisation.

(It would certainly be interesting to see a simpler proof)